# Get first smaller timestamp in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-timestamp

I have one table from this type:

```
Equipment   TimestampEqmt
truck1  timetruck1
truck2  timetruck2
truck3  timetruck3
truck1  timetruck4
truck2  timetruck5
truck3  timetruck6
```

and another with GPS coordinates for the trucks

```
Equipment   TimestamGPS X   Y   Z
truck1  TimestamGPS1    X1  Y1  Z1
truck2  TimestamGPS2    X2  Y2  Z2
truck3  TimestamGPS3    X3  Y3  Z3
truck1  TimestamGPS4    X4  Y4  Z4
truck2  TimestamGPS5    X5  Y5  Z5
truck3  TimestamGPS6    X6  Y6  Z6
truck1  TimestamGPS1    X7  Y7  Z7
truck2  TimestamGPS2    X8  Y8  Z8
truck3  TimestamGPS3    X9  Y9  Z9
truck1  TimestamGPS1    X10 Y10 Z10
truck2  TimestamGPS2    X11 Y11 Z11
truck3  TimestamGPS3    X12 Y12 Z12
```

How to get for every `TimestampEqmt` and `Equipment` from first table, first GPS coordinates where `TimestamGPS < TimestampEqmt`?

The result should be like this:

```
Equipment   TimestampEqmt   TimestamGPS X   Y   Z
truck1  timetruck1  TimestamGPS7    X7  Y7  Z7
truck2  timetruck2  TimestamGPS11   X11 Y11 Z11
truck3  timetruck3  TimestamGPS12   X12 Y12 Z12
```

Which means that `TimestamGPS7` is the first smaller timestamp depending on  `timetruck1` for `truck1`.

Comment: by `TIMESTAMP` you mean a column that has a `DATETIME` datatype and not a `TIMESTAMP` datatype?

Comment: How data `TimestamGPS7, TimestamGPS11, TimestamGPS12` listed under `TimestamGPS` ? when it's not exist in the table. Is that manupulated ?

Comment: Timestam is column that have datatime datatype like this 2018-07-18 08:31:17.367 or 2018-07-18 08:40:35.000 is the same. and TimestampGPS is the same format and always have data.

Comment: Nobody has been able to help you here because your question lacks clarity. You have data in the output that doesn't exist in the sample data. Your output is the largest values but you stated you wanted to smallest. You need to provide better details so others can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sorry for that ,I will give more details as edit to the question.